# Visual C++ .net: Disappearing project

Tags: .net, c++

This is a real newbie question:

If I create a simple project in .NET, lets say at c:\project\test,
and then change the directory name from project to say project2, when I try to open the .sln file my project will not open, I mean the .NET program opens and runs but nothing is there.  If I change the directory name back to project, it still will not open the project.  What is going on here?

Comment: Why don't just give me an answer instead of giving me a -1?  That is EXTREMELY RUDE.  I can see giving a minus number to someone who gives a stupid answer to a question, but I honestly don't know this.

Comment: Are you sure you don't know? When you add a project to a solution, how do you think visual studio refers to your project? Magic?

Comment: Of course not.  I opened the .sln file and then looked for an absolute path name which would explain the above.  I didn't see any reference to c:\project which would account for the disappearing project.  It was all relative addresses which would not change if I changed the directory name down one step in the tree.  Then I did a search on the directory name and still came up with nothing.

Comment: Anyway.  I didn't change the directory name above the .sln file so if it is using relative addressing it should find the .proj file one directory up.  The name change was toward root.  With relative addressing that shouldn't affect anything

Comment: I have done this many times. You must have missed something in the solution file...

Comment: I have just done it again.  1. I created a directory called delete_me 2. I then created a project named junk in directory delete_me.  3. I try opening the project .sln file and everything comes up ok.  4. I then change the name of delete_me to delete.  5.  I once again double click on the .sln file and this time the project will not come up.  6.  I search for delete_me and it does not appear in any of the files in the directory.

Comment: Somewhere there is some knowledge of the absolute directory name in the project, but I can't find it.

Comment: Paths in SLN files are relative, not absolute. You'll see something like ..\Project not c:\Project also it wont open because VS has unloaded the project. Right click and choose Reload Project. If you want to move a project, remove it from the solution, move it then re-add existing project (in it's new location)

Comment: Why not put up the contents of your sln file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jorgen was right.  It was a dumb question.  Nothing disappeared.  The answer is to find the moved project in the Solution Explorer and reload the project.  Then everything works just fine.

Answer (score 4):

Changing the directory name does not update the solution file. You can try opening .sln in notepad and fixing the path to the .vcxproj project file.

See [File Types and File Extensions in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhkhh4zs.aspx) for more information.

Comment: The .vcxproj project file is a relative address.  The relative address didn't change.  The change was toward root which shouldn't affect anything.  Yet it does.

Comment: Apologies. I haven't used VS for C++ since college. I wasn't 100% sure what the project file extension was.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really have to do with Visual Studio at all. If you change the directory of ANY file, any program that is associated with it obviously won't know where the heck it went!

Comment: But there has to be a way to move an entire project to another directory or change the directory name below a .NET project without losing every thing.  Right?